# Make ajax call in sequential order using jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a case in which ajax call need to be run in sequential order
So to maintain a Queue which keep on increasing run time so I used the following 
approach but seems to be not working.

```
var requestQueue=[];
   function processQueue() {
       var reqParam=requestQueue[0];
        $.ajax(reqParam).then(function() {
            requestQueue.shift();
            Logger.log("Queue is processed",requestQueue.length);
            if (requestQueue.length > 0) {
                processQueue();
            } else {
                Logger.log("Queue is processed");
            }
        }, function() {
            requestQueue.shift();
            console.log("Queue is processed",requestQueue.length);
            if (requestQueue.length > 0) {
                processQueue();
            } else {
                console.log("Queue is processed");
            }
        });
    }


//when new request trigger by user
   function onUserEvent(){
    if (requestQueue.length === 0) {
                                requestQueue.push(requestParameters);
                                processQueue();
                            } else {
                                requestQueue.push(requestParameters);
                            }
 }
```

Comment: Both of your functions are completely identical in your ajax call.

Comment: It is just a snap of code. the second half is triggered by the user.

Comment: Can you continue to nest the Ajax calls?

On success, call the next etc..

Comment: @Rastalamm I am calling processQueue on success of the Ajax call which doing the same suggested by you.

Comment: Yes you can. This code is using recursion to loop through the "requestQueue" array. However the anonymous callback function trailing the "then" function call is not formatted to do anything different. It's not needed.

Comment: Plus you are trying to use promises but this doesn't look correct

Comment: Is the last if statement part of a function?

Comment: @andremcgruder sorry for the confusion corrected the code

Comment: Have you tried using async: false ?

Comment: if you are trying to create a request queue you probably should have a function that allows the user to populate the reqestQueue array and then on that will iterate over that array, but each will have their individual triggering event.

Comment: the way you have it written now the array will never exceed the first value because you empty; the 'shift' function; the array once its length is more than 0.

Comment: @Chintan7027 async false will make the UI jerky  meanwhile the request is in progress.